# flutter: how to perform a task after the user returns from the launched url

Tags: android, flutter, url, url-launcher

Using url_launcher I launch a website inside my android flutter application. When the user quits the browser after some time I want to perform a task. But how do I recognize that the user has quit the browser and therefore returned to the application?